FFMPEG C++ Receiving udp stream with srt subs
I'm broadcasting some data as srt subtitles over udp and trying to receive and save it along with video stream. The following terminal pipeline works
ffmpeg -i udp://0.0.0.0:18565 -f srt -v verbose output.srt

But my code for it hangs on stream opening (av_open_input)
inputSubtitleCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
if (!inputSubtitleCtx) {
    return "Couldn't create input sub AVFormatContext";
}
if (avformat_open_input(&inputSubtitleCtx, "udp://0.0.0.0:18565", NULL, NULL) < 0) {
    return "Could not open subtitle input";
}

if (avformat_find_stream_info(inputSubtitleCtx, NULL) < 0) {
    return "Could not find stream information for subtitle file";
}

for (int i = 0; i < inputSubtitleCtx->nb_streams; i++) {
    AVStream* inStream = inputSubtitleCtx->streams[i];

    if (inStream->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_SUBTITLE) {
        AVStream* outStream = avformat_new_stream(avOutputCtxRec, NULL);
        subStreamIndexRec = outStream->index;

        if (!outStream) {
            return "Could not allocate output stream";
        }
        if (avcodec_parameters_copy(outStream->codecpar, inStream->codecpar) < 0) {
            return "Failed to copy codec parameters";
        }
    }
}

UDP stream with video is opened w/o problem.
